# The requested page can't be found in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I Assigned my Component profile page into Joomla Menu Item. when i access the particular menu Item. Its Display following Error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the menu item if it can be accessed by public, registered or special.

After checking your script I have found out that there are several mistakes that you have made. I cannot point out each mistake. To give you a way forward I would suggest you to make these change in truematrimony.php file

REPLACE THIS

```
// import joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

FOFDispatcher::getTmpInstance('com_truematrimony')->dispatch();
```

TO

```
// import joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

// Initialize the controller
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Truematrimony');
// Perform the Request task
$controller->execute(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('task', null, 'default', 'cmd'));
$controller->redirect();
```

Comment: Menu Item is Public access

Comment: Are you using any SEF component? Also my COmponent means did you develop any component? Is it a custom component?

Comment: Its My own Compoent and I Enabled SEF routing

Comment: Did you check disabling the SEF routing. If on disable it is working and when you enable it is not working that means there is problem with your component router file.

Comment: Problem zeroes down to your component. Can you upload the entire component somewhere? When I will have time I will check.

Comment: @Karthikmathesh Check your component's permission for public user group from the joomla admin panel.

Comment: Thanks for your Comments @AmitRay. But Its Not Working Till Now. I Attach my Component for your Suggestion. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/zelclqwjhegmj2r?oref=e&r=AANqcbK_B6rhkJleoDNsMgY06s8xa-vSWxrX7a-K4oP3spYivA8Rm8zTG8Mm-Jq_qu5ONdwv3GESFVQ9LRGQCDLNPFIENeeaYrhPbmvnKk0TVEyQiQXWW16NAXuwFbk2I0Jw3p37ubM9KmU94EJBWET6HyALQrDP9OkhQL7mtdewLg&sm=1

Comment: Install the component Assign the Profile and Search to the Menu Item. Its shows 403 For Access Bitten Error/

Comment: @Karthikmathesh You have several coding errors and I have to check it thoroughly. It may take time. One big mistake I found is you have not used `defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');` on many pages which makes your code vulnerable. And you have also not folowed the Joomla MVC pattern. How to cal model methods in views, how to use controllers etc. I have to go through it and let you know when I have some free time.

Comment: @Karthikmathesh Sorry I was out of station due to holidays. I will check it soon and let you know.

Comment: @Karthikmathesh There are several errors but I have suggested a method that can help you. I am really sorry as I can go into all the codes.

Comment: @AmitRay Thank you for your Valuable time spend to me. I Try to Develop Component using MVC structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seem to indicate that the component is working when accessing it directly with an url, but not when accessed as a menu item, is this so? In that case there must be something wrong with the menu link. If accessing the url directly after the menu link is created does not work, then some option from the menu must affect how your component is working. Try identifying where the access forbidden exception is raised. Try f.ex to add something like

`print_r($option); die('Exit execution');`

in relevant functions in the search model in your component, or similar in  the controller. This will help reveal where the error is.